# What are common methods for storing global / shared app logins / passwords?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, security, passwords

The team I work on designs a number of applications that are used across the organization internally.  We use a MySQL database and don't really care to track MySQL access on a per user basis as it's not necessary.  We've established app based user accounts so we can monitor usage and access on a per app basis and we've designed the apps to auto-login as long as a user has assigned access for that specific app.

Currently, we are storing the login information in DSN files that are read when creating a connection in app.  This has been the easiest way to separate the login information from the app since this information sometimes needs to change.  However, this is obviously not very secure as anyone who finds the DSN files will have the users and passwords for the apps.

We've also utilized the Resources file in our C# apps to manage logins.

Going forward, I want to consider better methods for managing these app passwords.  As noted above, we don't want to maintain user accounts since that would be too much maintenance... the app accounts have been a good balance for us of not having too many accounts but at least being able to track usage on a per app basis.

I'm not looking for lectures on security about the methods we've used as I know they aren't secure.

But does anyone have suggestions for a more secure method that would also be somewhat easy to maintain?  I've heard of others using app logins/passwords like we are doing, but I'm not really sure how they maintained their logins.

Comment: Would [integrated security](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-authentication-windows-native.html) be an option? That just means you have to give your apps' user accounts (for example their app pool users if running in IIS) privileges and you don't need to store passwords or usernames anywhere outside of windows.

Comment: See connection strings .com  The best is to use Integrated Security which uses Windows Credentials.  Windows requires a remote PC to be in same group as local PC and uses Encryption to send data between PC and required the user to have accounts on both local and remote PCs : https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Comment: But wouldn't integrated security require that we are managing user accounts on the MySQL database for connections?  Or is there a way to tie a generic app account to a user through integrated security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stumbling on this later, integrated Windows security is obviously the best option as has been pointed out above, but in my case, that's overkill since I'd have to maintain access on a per user basis for 300+ users (that's just not feasible with my small team nor is it necessary).  We've got the apps setup with app credentials.

So the way I found to manage security for config files is one of two ways:

- You can encrypt credentials stored in config files:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files

```
<configProtectedData defaultProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">  
  <providers>  
    <add name="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider"   
      type="System.Configuration.RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider, ... />  
    <add name="DataProtectionConfigurationProvider"   
      type="System.Configuration.DpapiProtectedConfigurationProvider, ... />  
  </providers>  
</configProtectedData>
```

- or you can store credentials as secrets:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=windows

using the secrets manager, the secrets are stored here:

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\UserSecrets\<user_secrets_id>\secrets.json
```